# signature_invalid when trying to get request_token (Yahoo)

Tags: php, oauth, yahoo, yahoo-api

I started to develop a script to get contacts from Yahoo's user. Before to get contacts, I am having problem to get request token, when I perform a request for a link like this:

```
<a class="yahoo" href="https://api.login.yahoo.com/oaut/v2/get_request_token?oauth_nonce=<?php echo uniqid() ?>&oauth_timestamp=<?php echo time() ?>&oauth_consumer_key=<?php echo $yahoo_consumer_key ?>&oauth_signature_method=plaintext&oauth_signature=<?php echo $yahoo_consumer_secret ?>&oauth_version=1.0&xoauth_lang_pref=en-us&oauth_callback=<?php echo urlencode('http://myfullurl.com') ?>">Get Contacts</a>
```

I get an HTTP header 401 Forbidden with message: oauth_problem=signature_invalid

I do not know if I am setting the link correctly but It was what I have understand through http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-sign-plaintext.html

Reference: http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-requesttoken.html

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `https://api.login.yahoo.com/oaut/v2/get_request_token` has to be a server-side call, not a link the user has to click.

If you don't know how to do that, you should probably use some [PHP OAuth library](https://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/) that handles this for you.

Then, as Yahoo is stating in [their documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-sign-plaintext.html):

> For requests to get_request_token, the Token Secret is absent. Include only the Consumer Secret followed by an "&" character.

your `oauth_signature` should be:

```
&oauth_signature=<?php echo $yahoo_consumer_secret . "&" ?>
```

Comment: Dont need to be a server-side request, read 6.1.1 here http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#auth_step1. Must be a HTTP request with GET or POST, PHP OAuth library just perform a request via cURL that is the same if I perform a request by user clicking on link. I think that "&" at the end of consumer secret is just for separate from other variable in case of GET, but I have tried it too but did not work.

Comment: No, it is not the same. The documentation states: `**The Consumer** obtains an unauthorized Request Token by asking the Service Provider to issue a Token.` *The Consumer* is your web application and **not** the user's browser! The `response token` would also be sent back to the user's browser and not to your web application, where you need it. Then you also certainly don't want the `consumer_secret` to be available to the public in your HTML source code.